# Make the URL be more readable

Tags: angularjs

## Search page

```
<p class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <button class="btn_1 green" ui-sref='tour_package.pickup-flights({destination: q_param.destination_city, departure_date_range: q_param.date_range})'><i class="icon-search"></i>Search now</button>
</p>
```

## After clicking search and head for next page, the url turned out to be so so ugly.

```
    http://xxx/#/tour_package/2016~2F07~2F22%20-2016~2F07~2F25
```

It should be `http://xxx/#/tour_package/2016/07/22-2016/07/25`

Comment: What does your state code look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your state URL looks like this:

`http://xxx/#/tour_package/{{destination}}/{{departure_date_range}}`

You need to get rid of the "/" before sending it to the state.

Convert "2016/07/22" to "2016-07-22" so the url can then look like:

`http://xxx/#/tour_package/2016-07-22/2016-07-25`

The "/" just adds confusion to the URL. You're defining only 2 state params but the multiple "/" makes it 5.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please upvote it or mark it as correct. Thanks